# Merging values for one column and summing up the values in the second column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm a total newbie to Oracle SQL. I'm trying to perform an operation on about three tables. Basically, I have three tables: Artist, Transaction, Work. I'm trying to retrieve the artist who has the most works of art sold. When I run the query I get duplicate values and I'm not entirely sure how to merge the columns.

Here is the query I initially execute

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME || '' || LASTNAME AS ARTISTNAME, TITLE, SALESPRICE
FROM DTOOHEY.ARTIST A, DTOOHEY.WORK W, DTOOHEY.TRANS T
WHERE A.ARTISTID = W.ARTISTID
AND W.WORKID = T.WORKID
AND DATESOLD IS NOT NULL;
```

[Here is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv4hs.png)
What I want to achieve is to merge the Artist Names and then have their Sales Price summed up. For example, for the Artist Joan Miro I'd like for it to show only one value as "Joan Miro" and the Sales Price is a sum of the merged rows (400+200 = 600). So something like

```
Artist Name | SalesPrice    

Joan Miro   | 600
```

Is such a thing possible? I am not entirely sure how to use the MERGE function and I'm not sure if that's what I need to use here.

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have indeed used GROUP BY. I have tried this query as well:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME || '' || LASTNAME AS ARTISTNAME, TITLE, SUM(SALESPRICE)
FROM DTOOHEY.ARTIST A, DTOOHEY.WORK W, DTOOHEY.TRANS T
WHERE A.ARTISTID = W.ARTISTID
AND W.WORKID = T.WORKID
AND DATESOLD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME;
```

I get an error saying:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 42 Column: 51
```

Comment: Based on your updated question, the reason you get the error is due to the fact that you are selecting `TITLE` in the select. You cannot select rows which are not being grouped on, or aggregated on. Remove the `TITLTE` value from the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the `group by` clause is for. It lets you specify which columns should define a group of rows (in your case  - the artist's first and last name) and makes you apply some aggregate function (in your case - sum) on the others. I.e.:

```
SELECT   FIRSTNAME || '' || LASTNAME AS ARTISTNAME, SUM(SALESPRICE)
FROM     DTOOHEY.ARTIST A, DTOOHEY.WORK W, DTOOHEY.TRANS T
WHERE    A.ARTISTID = W.ARTISTID AND
         W.WORKID = T.WORKID AND
         DATESOLD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME;
```

General comment:
Implicit joins (having multiple tables in the `from` clause) has been considered as deprecated, and ill-advised for some years now. You should probably use an explicit join clause:

```
SELECT   FIRSTNAME || '' || LASTNAME AS ARTISTNAME, SUM(SALESPRICE)
FROM     DTOOHEY.ARTIST A
JOIN     DTOOHEY.WORK W ON A.ARTISTID = W.ARTISTID
JOIN     DTOOHEY.TRANS T ON W.WORKID = T.WORKID
WHERE    DATESOLD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME;
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I did try Group By. I get an error saying "not a GROUP BY expression".

Comment: GROUP BY is definitely the solution. The error is probably due to too many columns in the select, or not enough columns in the group by.

Comment: @GavinCattell Ok, I have removed the "TITLE" from the query. I think having the Title there is what created a conflict. It seemed to have worked now. Thank you both so much for your help :)

Comment: @GavinCattell you have the `title` in your select list, but it is neither in the `group by` clause  nor does it have an aggregate function applied to it. Which kind of makes the error make sense - if I painted two pieces - X for 100$ and Y for 200$, I'd clearly have a sum of 300$ in sales, but what would the title be in such a query?

Comment: Arg, sorry, that last comment was aimed at @GautamNath, not Gavin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`GROUP BY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html) and `SUM`.

Also, for clarity, I recommend ANSI join syntax.

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME || '' || LASTNAME AS ARTISTNAME, SUM(SALESPRICE) AS TOTAL_SALESPRICE
FROM DTOOHEY.ARTIST A
JOIN DTOOHEY.WORK W ON A.ARTISTID = W.ARTISTID
JOIN DTOOHEY.TRANS T ON W.WORKID = T.WORKID
WHERE DATESOLD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME;
```